# El Capitan sluggish mouse scrolling

Tags: mouse, macos

I'm using a Logitech Performance Mouse MX.  Since upgrading to OS X 10.11 some apps responded sluggishly to mouse scrolling while others are fine.  For instance Safari responds like it used to but other apps like Xcode are very sluggish to scroll.  It feels like the top speed for scrolling has been capped for these apps when using the mouse.  Any idea what changed in OS X 10.11 that would cause this behavior?

Answer (score 2):

Updating to the latest version of the Logitech Control Center fixed the issue.
http://support.logitech.com/software/logitech-control-center-for-macintosh-os-x